What field in event log manifest become a "Source" in Event Logging window?
I wrote event log manifest file with provider and channel. Now, I have to split it to different event sources, and now I am a little bit confused how to do this. What part of manifest becomes a source in terms of event viewer?
In my opinion I should write few providers and use same channel for all of them. Is it correct?
